# Can't find if a value exists in a dictionary from input in Python

Tags: python

```
my_file = open("input.txt",'r')
d = {}
for line in my_file:
    key = line[0]
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = [line.strip("\n")]
    else:
        d[key].append(line.strip("\n"))

for key in d:
    print(key,d[key])
print("")
find_word = input("Search a word: ")
for value in d:
    if find_word in d.values():
       print("Word is found")
       break
    else:
        print("Word not found")
        break
```

I've seen some other questions about this question, but they seem to be more complex than mine. I'm a beginner, and my code always returns "not found".

Comment: Why do you have `for value in d:` if you never use `value` in the loop?

Comment: Maybe the lines in your file have spaces at the end. Try using `line.strip()` instead of `line.strip("\n")`. That will remove all surrounding whitespace.

Comment: `values()` will itself give a list, containing lists of `values`. In other words, you end up with a nested list. Your word will not compare equal to any of the sublists

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems your dictionary is the wrong way around. Searching the values of a dictionary is grossly inefficient; they're a data structure that relies on searching for _keys_. Searching for keys is constant time, but searching the values will be proportional to how long, and nested, your values are.

Comment: @Barmar I thought value was a keyword, but now see it isn't. I replaced it with key and it still won't find a word

Comment: @roganjosh I know that you're not supposed to set it up this way, but this is for an assignment and we have to find if a value exists in a dictionary

Comment: "Find if a value exists in a dictionary" almost always means "check to see if the 'value' is a _key_ in the dictionary". Maybe you are correct in the specifics of your task, but it's also worth double-checking because this exercise can only illustrate why you _wouldn't_ want to set up a dictionary this way around.

Comment: Do you really want the first character of ```line``` (that's what ```line[0]``` will do) to be your dictionary key?

Comment: Can you show an example of what's in `input.txt` and what you're searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `d.values()` as the list to iterate over in the `for` loop. Then test whether the search word is in each list.

```
for word_list in d.values():
    if find_word in word_list:
        print("Word is found")
        break
else:
    print("Word is not found")
```

Notice that the `else:` that prints that the word is not found should not be in the `if`, it should be in `for`. This way it prints the message only if none of the lists in the dictionary contains the word. The `else:` clause of a loop is executed if the loop finishes normally, rather than being exited with `break`.

You can also use the `any()` function:

```
if any(find_word in word_list for word_list in d.values()):
    print("Word is found")
else:
    print("Word is not found")
```

Comment: That's intentional. Read what I wrote right after it.

Comment: The variables name wordlist and word_list doesn't match, therefore causing and error

Comment: This doesn't find the words, I tried running it with a sample file on my local, when you get to if find_word in world_list it does an exact match but the values "word_list" at that point is not a list of words is a list of lines, unless he is looking for the whole line it won't work.

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz I assumed the file is one word per line.

Comment: <<In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.>>

Comment: You don't need a ```for``` loop for that checking. A simple ```if find_word in d.values()``` will do the job.

Comment: No, because `d.values()` is a list of lists.

Comment: The question says "if a value exists". It doesn't say "if a value is a substring". So I look for exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what you are looking for

```
find_word = input("Search a word: ")
found = False

for _list in d.values():

    for element in _list:

        if element.find(find_word) != -1:

            print('Found')
            found = True
            break

    if found:
        break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

when you use the keyword `in` to perform a search it needs to be an exact match, therefore if you do `'test' in ['test2', 'test3']` it will evaluate to false as it's not an exact match, in top of this, the values in your dictionary keys are lists of lists instead of 1 level lists, such as:

`dict_values([['text'], .... ['textn']])`

causing the condition to be:

`'word' in [[...], ..., [..]]`

This will never match.

You need a secondary for to iterate among the sub lists combined with `find` that looks for sequence of strings inside another give string, because the items in the sub lists are complete lines, allowing partial match.

Comment: The issue is not substrings, it's trying to match strings against sublists

Comment: you are completely right @roganjosh, in my answer I fixed the issue with a second for, I should make it more clear, let me edit it, or would you like to edit my answer yourself ? Best regards

Comment: The values in his dictionary are lists of strings, not lists of lists.

Comment: `d[key].append(line.strip("\n"))` appends a string to the list, it doesn't append a list.

Comment: that's right, but if you call d.values() it returns a list of list that you iterate with the first for making each element a list

Comment: @Barmar dict_values([['la;slkalsklask', "lg,vtlgekw 'sg"], [' sdksd', ' dsjaksdjkds qdwnqnqw', ...]]

Comment: let me rephrase my explanation